About density in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
Suppose that $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.
Does anyone have any suggestions to prove the following
$$\overline{\mathbb{R}\left(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)+\mathbb{Z}^{3}}=\mathbb{R}^{3} \hspace{1cm}?$$
I tried using sequences, I cannot obtain a sequence of integers that converges and satisfies the convergence in each component.
Here
$\mathbb{R}^{3}=\{ (x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) : x_{i}\in\mathbb{R},\hspace{0.1cm}\forall j=1,2,3 \}$.
$\mathbb{R}\left(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)=\{ r\left(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)=\left(r,r\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, r\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right) : r\in\mathbb{R}\}$ in other words the spanned (over $\mathbb{R}$) of $\left(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)$.
Thanks

Choose $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2=\lambda_3 = \sqrt{2}$. Let $l:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be $l(x) = x_2-x_3$ and let $H_n = \{ x | l(x) = n \}$. Note that $H= \cup_n H_n$ is closed and strictly contained in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Define the map
$\phi:\mathbb{Z}^3 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$\phi(n,t) = (t, t \sqrt{2}, t \sqrt{2})$ and note that $\phi(n,t) \in H$ for all $n,t$. In particular, the closure of the range is strictly contained in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Thanks, for the reply.
If $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\not=\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}$ the equality would be valid?
